# Runtime Error 6054 referencing all docmd.browseto Navigation subform pathways all of a sudden

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

HELP Please...

All of sudden all of the VBA docmd.browseto code within the entire navigation form has been producing a runtime error 6054 referencing issues with the pathway. These lines of code have worked for months and then all of a sudden stopped working. They work in a backup version from a few days ago when I open it now. I cant figure it out. As far as I can tell the pathways are accurate. I havent changed them, nor have I renamed the main navigation form.

navigation form = frmNavigation example of navigationsubform = frmNewServiceSession

‘DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmnewclientsinfo", "frmNavigation.navigationsubform", , , acFormEdit’

.... regardless of what navigation subform I reference I get the same error code. Again, this worked fine earlier.

Edit*** To test things a bit I had imported frmNavigation and frmNewServiceSession into my most recent backup and they communicate just fine using the exact vba as above.... Something strange is going on

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening although I dont exactly know why.  Open to insight, but resolved the immediate issue.

Resolution:

I use to have a Timer form open hidden on autoexec but moved it an action within the Login form on OK button click.  For some reason that difference messed with all of the BrowseTo functions.

Thanks